# Sometimes the v=<version number> parameter is added to the product URL

Tags: commerce

I have a new Drupal 8 site running commerce. When I view a product, most of the time the clean URL is perfect. Other times, it has a version parameter attached to it. I can access the page and no parameter, then refresh and I get a ?v=2 or something like that. I'm baffled. Has anyone experienced this issue? We're afraid that if users copy this link (with parameter) to other sites, it will cause us duplicate issues with SEO.

I'm not sure what I need to post here for help, so if anyone can help, let me know and I'll provide anything I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've got more than 1 variation on a product. The v  parameter allows you (and drupal commerce) to directly link to the product page with the correct variant set as the selected one

For example you have "t shirts" product with variations for colour. You might want to link directly from the product listing page/cart/anywhere else to a specific colour tie.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. None of our products have more than 1 variation. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not really I guess it could depend on lots of different things how your sites been built so not sure I can help much further. Are you sure you dont have variations? As I can understand if sometimes you had "?v=1" and sometimes nothing. But in your original message you said you get "?v=2" which does suggest you have more than 1 variation

Comment: I found the issue. It was a major bonehead move on my part. I use the product variation title in my grid views that displays the products and that was linking to the variation rather than the actual product. Your answer pointed me in the right direction so I really appreciate it!!

Comment: some of them had 2 or 3 variations originally but we took those out. I guess I left #2 or #3 in some cases.